# Import Neo4j data to Gephi 0.9.1

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, gephi, graphml

I want to import neo4j node information to Gephi. Just advised from the web, and I followed the guide and try to import data to Gephi.
[Neo4j shell tool](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools#graphml-export)

However, no response when try to open the graphml file. Is there any limit of graphml export to Gephi? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Really, I don't know if there is a limit on graphml with Gephi.

There is also an APOC procedure to stream data from neo4j to Gephi : https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_streaming_data_to_gephi

And also a proc to export as graphml : https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_graphml_import_export